# Facebook graph API public pages access not retrieved objects

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook granted my app the public pages access. I'm trying to get some public pages posts and users comments, reactions and shares. However I can only get the comments. Cannot get which user is author of this comment. Also reactions (like, wow, sad ...) is not retrieved as well as shares. Do I have to submit any other requests to be able to retrieve reactions, shares and comments authors (name and ID)?

Below is the Graph API request and response sample. You can notice from the request that I requested **from** to get the user write the comment to detect gender using some AI model and number of friends for this user (total count) to get the comment reach. And also I requested the **reactions** and **shares**. From the response From is not retrieved for the post it self or comments on the post, also reactions and shares are not retrieved

**Request**

```
PublicPage/feed?fields=from,likes,shares,message,reactions,created_time,type,comments{from,likes,created_time,comments{reactions,message,from,created_time},reactions,message}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "message": "This is test",
      "created_time": "2019-04-09T13:55:48+0000",
      "type": "status",
      "comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "from": {
              "name": "Public page user",
              "id": "141606109666"
            },
            "created_time": "2019-04-09T14:02:17+0000",
            "message": "This is reply"

Zahran",
            "id": "10156775193664667_10156775203269667"
          },
          {
            "created_time": "2019-04-09T14:03:30+0000",
            "message": "reply on comment1",
            "id": "10156775193664667_10156775205534667"
          },
          {
            "created_time": "2019-04-09T14:14:11+0000",
            "message": "reply on comment2",
            "id": "10156775193664667_10156775221109667"
          }
        ],
        "paging": {
          "cursors": {
            "before": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZANVEF4TlRZAM056VXlNRE15TmprMk5qYzZANVFUxTkRneE9EVXpOdz09",
            "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZANVEF4TlRZAM056VXlNakV4TURrMk5qYzZANVFUxTkRneE9USTFNUT09"
          }
        }
      },
      "id": "141606109666_10156775193664667"
    }
```

Comment: what would you need the user details for? anyway, you should add your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't need any user details. I just need the the total number of reactions, the user who write the comment and the number of shares for the post. And what code you need me to post? It is the Graph API behavior which am asking about!

Comment: "the user who wrote the comment" - that is user details. what do you need this for, if i may ask? i assume it is not available for privacy reasons.

Comment: code to post: you DID try something, and did not get expected results, right? so show us exactly what you tried. it does not have to be code, it can also be a specific api call. you are trying to do something that does not work, so tell us how we can reproduce it. you should always do that. makes it a lot easier to help :)

Comment: @luschn I edited the question.

Comment: _“You can notice from the request that I requested from to get the user write the comment to detect gender using some AI model and number of friends for this user (total count) to get the comment reach”_ - the `gender` field of the user object is only available with the user’s consent, so I doubt Facebook wants you to try and infer that from the user name either; and the number of friends of a user is also only available when the user actively gives your app permission.

Comment: There are several questions on here already where people ask about getting the `from` field for page comment’s, even when using a page access token for the page in question that only seems to work under certain conditions. I am pretty sure that for privacy reasons, you can not get that at all, when just accessing public pages you have no admin access to.